# Remote push notification not firing off using react native fcm

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-fcm

I'm using the firebase .on('value') listener in my constructor function inside my Feed component. When a value is added to the firebase database this fires off and when I use this.showLocalNotification() it works. However, when I use this.sendRemoteNotification(), no dice. The function is fired off as I am able to console log data inside that function, but it fails to show a notification when the app is in the foreground, background, or not on at all. I have all of my capabilities check on in Xcode, I'm running this on an iOS 8 Device, and I'm using `react-native-fcm 16.0.0`.

This is my `Feed` component with my constructor that includes the firebase listener and push notification functions.

```
registerKilledListener();


class Feed extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: "Active Jobs",
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="newspaper" size={28} color={COLOR.ICON} />
    )
  }; // navigationOptions
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      token: "",
      tokenCopyFeedback: ""
    }


    database.ref("OpenRequests/").on("value", snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();

      let obj = data[Object.keys(data)[Object.keys(data).length - 1]]

      //  this.showLocalNotification(obj)
      this.sendRemoteNotification(obj)

    });

  }

  async componentWillMount() {

    console.log(this.props.navigation)
    registerAppListener(this.props.navigation);
    FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif => {
      this.setState({
        initNotif: notif
      });
      if (notif && notif.targetScreen === "detail") {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail");
        }, 500);
      }
    });

    try {
      let result = await FCM.requestPermissions({
        badge: false,
        sound: true,
        alert: true
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
      // console.log('Setting token: ', token)
      // console.log("TOKEN (getFCMToken)", token);
      this.setState({
        token: token || ""
      });
    });

    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      FCM.getAPNSToken().then(token => {
        // console.log("APNS TOKEN (getFCMToken)", token);
      });
    }
    FCM.createNotificationChannel({
      id: 'default',
      name: 'Default',
      description: 'used for example',
      priority: 'high'
    })

    // topic example
    // FCM.subscribeToTopic('sometopic')
    // FCM.unsubscribeFromTopic('sometopic')
  }

  sendRemoteNotification(data) {
    let body;
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      body = {
        to: this.state.token,
        data: {
          custom_notification: {
            title: "Simple FCM Client",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            sound: "default",
            priority: "high",
            show_in_foreground: true,
            // targetScreen: "feed"
          }
        },
        priority: 10
      };
    } else {
      body = {
        to: this.state.token,
        notification: {
          title: "Simple FCM Client",
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          sound: "default"
        },
        // data: {
        //   targetScreen: "feed"
        // },
        priority: 10
      };
    }

    firebaseClient.send(JSON.stringify(body), "notification");
  }

  showLocalNotification(data) {
    console.log(data)
    FCM.presentLocalNotification({
      channel: 'default',
      id: new Date().valueOf().toString(), // (optional for instant notification)
      title: "INCOMING REQUEST", // as FCM payload
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // as FCM payload (required)
      sound: "bell.mp3", // "default" or filename
      priority: "high", // as FCM payload
      click_action: "com.myapp.MyCategory", // as FCM payload - this is used as category identifier on iOS.
      badge: 10, // as FCM payload IOS only, set 0 to clear badges
      number: 10, // Android only
      ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // Android only
      auto_cancel: true, // Android only (default true)
      large_icon: "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/small-boy-cartoon_318-38077.jpg", // Android only
      icon: "ic_launcher", // as FCM payload, you can relace this with custom icon you put in mipmap
      big_text: "Show when notification is expanded", // Android only
      sub_text: "This is a subText", // Android only
      color: "red", // Android only
      vibrate: 300, // Android only default: 300, no vibration if you pass 0
      wake_screen: true, // Android only, wake up screen when notification arrives
      group: "group", // Android only
      picture: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png", // Android only bigPicture style
      ongoing: true, // Android only
      my_custom_data: "my_custom_field_value", // extra data you want to throw
      lights: true, // Android only, LED blinking (default false)
      show_in_foreground: true // notification when app is in foreground (local & remote)
    });
  }
```